# How to write a correct path for Python "os.scandir()"?

Tags: python, windows, path, operating-system

I want to make a program which checks if the file exists in 2 different directories at the same time.

I figured out how to access the PC directory, but I am having troubles with the SD Card directory path.

```py
import os

Phonebasepath = '//This PC/Phone name/SD card/Music'
with os.scandir(Phonebasepath) as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.is_file():
            print(entry.name)
```

This code should print all the files in the dictionary, but I get an error like this:
[WinError 53] The network path was not found: '//This PC/Phone name/SD card/Music'

I changed some directory names for safety.

Comment: How would you specify such a path on the command line?

Comment: I copied this from Windows file manager.

Comment: "This PC\Phone Name" has no UNC provider. It's a shell extension. Getting access to the shell namespace requires COM, i.e. PyWin32 win32com.

Comment: Could you please change the path into a correct one? I am a little confused.

Comment: There is no file path to correct. It's a path in the shell (Explorer) namespace, and you'll need to use its COM API.

Comment: Thank you very much